# How can I provide input field arguments with apollo federation 2?

Tags: go, graphql, microservices, apollo-federation, gqlgen

I am trying to federate two of my micro services with apollo gql federation 2.
I have successfully connected the two services through the federation with the following schemas:

**Subgraph1 - Product**

```
type Product @key(fields: "id") {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    description: String
    price: Int!
    category: [Category!]
  }

type Category @key(fields: "id") {
    id: ID!
  }

type Query {
    product(id: ID!): Product
  }
```

**Subgraph 2 - Category**

```
type Category @key(fields: "id") {
    id: ID!
    title: String
  }
```

and the following query

```
query Product($productId: ID!) {
  product(id: $productId) {
    id
    title
    category {
      id
      title
    }
  }
}
```

gives a desired result

However, what if I wanted to add some filter on the returned categories for a given product. Lets say I only wanted to have the ones with title "sport", so the query would look like this instead:

```
query Product($productId: ID!) {
  product(id: $productId) {
    id
    title
    category(searchTerm: "sport") {
      id
      title
    }
  }
}
```

A normal way of doing the input argument would be simply just

```
type Product @key(fields: "id") {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    description: String
    price: Int!
    category(searchTerm: String): [Category!]
  }
```

Is this achievable when federating the services? I am not sure how the input field is provided to the second subgraph?

I tried to add the input as a part of the type in the first subgraph, however it does not seem to pass the search term to the next graph.